# What the event handler if I want to input the value of Time when I change it?

Tags: customization, acumatica

On screen CRCase, I added new field UsrFinishDate and it will generate when I assign the owner for the case and I allowed users to change DateTime of UsrFinishDate if they want. For my purpose are:

1. For the default value of UsrFinishDate will get from SLAETA when I assign User, it will be calculated.
2. If owners want to add more days over the SLA so they can change the DateTime on UsrFinishDate and it should get the new Date and current time when they change. But about my problem, it's not calculated correctly because it got time at 12:00 AM or 12:00 PM all the time while I'm changing UsrFinishDate and time it still got the same current time even user have already changed it.

[image]
[image]
Below is my coding:

```
 protected void CRCase_UsrFinishDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e, PXFieldDefaulting InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  CRCase row = e.Row as CRCase;
  CRCaseExt rowExt = PXCache<CRCase>.GetExtension<CRCaseExt>(row);

  if (row == null || row.AssignDate == null) return;

  if (row.ClassID != null && row.Severity != null)
  {
    var severity = (CRClassSeverityTime)PXSelect<CRClassSeverityTime,
                        Where<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID>>,
                        And<CRClassSeverityTime.severity, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.severity>>>>>.
                        Select(Base, row.ClassID, row.Severity);
    if (severity != null && severity.TimeReaction != null)
    {
      e.NewValue = ((DateTime)row.AssignDate).AddMinutes((int)severity.TimeReaction);
      e.Cancel = true;
    }
  }

  if (row.Severity != null && row.ContractID != null)
  {
    var template = (Contract)PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>.Select(Base, row.ContractID);
    if (template == null) return;

    var sla = (ContractSLAMapping)PXSelect<ContractSLAMapping,
                      Where<ContractSLAMapping.severity, Equal<Required<CRCase.severity>>,
                      And<ContractSLAMapping.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>>.
                      Select(Base, row.Severity, template.TemplateID);
    if (sla != null && sla.Period != null)
    {
      e.NewValue = ((DateTime)row.AssignDate).AddMinutes((int)sla.Period);
      e.Cancel = true;
    }
  }
}

protected void CRCase_UsrFinishDate_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = e.Row as CRCase;
  CRCaseExt rowExt = PXCache<CRCase>.GetExtension<CRCaseExt>(row);
    if(rowExt != null)
    {
      System.DateTime today = (DateTime)rowExt.UsrFinishDate;
      System.TimeSpan duration = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0);
      rowExt.UsrFinishDate = today.Add(duration);
    }
}
```

It seems not correct at all. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please describe your usage scenario? Especially this information will be helpful:

1. What date do you want to store in this field?
2. What do you expect to see there? Date? Time?
3. DAC field definition and attributes
4. What do you mean under "duration" field?

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, let me describe and update more information about my question above.